# Best way to detect that a ZSH scope runs inside a VScode's Terminal?

Tags: zsh, environment-variables, visual-studio-code

When I run build commands in Visual Studio Code I want to invoke my whole custom shell that I also use for macOS, thus I invoke;

```
source ~/.zshrc && sync_all_shell_env
```

There is a small problem tho; I have some periodic checks that can be triggered (like some other syncs, checks and updates). I would prefer to not prompt these while I trigger my build commands in VScode. So it would be something like `$IS_VSCODE` like I also use `$IS_LINUX`, `$IS_MACOS`, `$IS_PI`, `$IS_AT_HOME` etc.

What would be the most certain way to know that the shell, in that moment in time, is triggered inside VScode? Is there a unique variable that I can check that ensures I'm inside VScode exclusively?

When I run;

```
printenv | grep VSCODE
```

I seem to be able to use those to detect it. They don't seem to live in my normal shell.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I fixed it like so;

```
export IS_VSCODE=false

if [[ $(printenv | grep -c "VSCODE_") -gt 0 ]]; then
    export IS_VSCODE=true
fi

if $IS_VSCODE; then
    echo "VSCODE YES!"
fi
```